# carto api with javascript using online carto db. Argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type geometry

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto-js

I am using cartodb api to fetch the geojson from the cartodb data set using this code

```
var map = L.map('map',{ center: [-35.1393961, 149.8530818], zoom: 13});
var alpha=map.getBounds();

var lat0=alpha.getNorthEast().lat;


var long0=map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng;

var lat1=map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat;
var long1=map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng;


// Add Tile Layer basemap
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFzaGlyaWx5YXMiLCJhIjoiY2l4NzdzMmhjMDB0dDJ0bXN0NW5jc3cwayJ9.UNDyJQP92EC0ToFilX28lA', {
maxZoom: 18,
id: 'your.mapbox.project.id',
accessToken: 'your.mapbox.public.access.token'}).addTo(map);


// Global Variables
// Will go here
var coffeeShopLocations = null;

// Database Queries
// Get all coffee cafes from dataset
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM zearch_nsw_19042016 WHERE the_geom && ST_MakeEnvelope("+long1+", "+lat1+", "+long0+", "+lat0+", 4326);";
function showAll(){
  $.getJSON("https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql/?q="+sqlQuery+"&api_key={key}&format=geojson&callback=?", function(data) {


  console.log(data);



       });
};



// Run showAll function automatically when document loads
$( document ).ready(function() {
  showAll();
});
```

While executing the query on the cartodb it is returning correct result but here at first it was showing invalid geom object but when I outputed the geojson it is showing this error

> argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type geometry

What is wrong? 
The query works fine when implemented on the cartodb or postgis database. But when used with cartodb api it generates the error on geojson

Comment: Please  [edit] the question to specify the database used for the data source. If it's not PostgreSQL/PostGIS then the syntax error is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `&&` as the [PostGIS "overlaps" spatial binary operator](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/geometry_overlaps.html).

Make sure that both sides of that operation are *either* a `geometry` *or* a `geography`. One possibility is that `the_geom` is a PostGIS `geography` and that the result of `ST_MakeEnvelope()` is a `geometry`.

Also pay attention to the order of the operands in the [`ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, srid)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) call, as it expects `xmin` to be less than `xmax` (idem for `y`).

Comment: I am getting correct answer using the query on cartodb(online) the problem arises when i fetch the result using the carto api and print the geojson it is stating that the "argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type geometry". If i dont apply where clause it fetches the result and plots the polygon perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a WHERE as you have it structured, the statement expects a Boolean return....

Instead, I think you want something more like this example:

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE the_geom && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-73.9980, 40.726), ST_Point(-73.995, 40.723)), 4326)
```

This is from the section "Query Records in a Bounding Box":

https://carto.com/docs/tips-and-tricks/advanced-analysis

Comment: thanks for the help tried it as well and same problem "argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type geometry". I think there is some issue with the carto api

Answer (score 0):

So i found out the solution. First of all the Where statement in postgis/ cartodb requires it to be boolean. The cartodb online was showing the result because sometimes the ui doesnt show the error and skirts around it to show the result according to cartodb help support.

Second of all i used this query which was suggested by the carto support personal to get the required result from the cartodb via carto sql api.

```
SELECT * from zearch_nsw_19042016 WHERE ST_Intersects(the_geom, ST_MakeEnvelope("+long1+", "+lat1+", "+long0+", "+lat0+", 4326))
```

It worked like a charm.

Thanks all for helping